# Quickest way to fix a wet carpet that smells

Tags: water, carpet, smell

So I have messed up. I am moving house.

On Saturday I hired a carpet cleaner and ran it round my flat. Something went a bit wrong when I was doing the bedroom and it didn't dry the carpet very well. I wake up on Tuesday morning to find the carpet really smells of .. wet carpet.

The carpet isn't soaking, but just feels damp to the touch.

I need to vacate the property by Friday. What are my options?

I am at work until then, so can't get any equipment. I might be able to get a carpet cleaner though. Could running over the carpet again fix things?

Comment: The problem with Brits (and Brit-like folks) saying that they "hired" something is that to us 'Mericans it sounds like you hired someone, not something. I initially assumed that a cleaning service had done a poor job and wondered why you hadn't simply called them back. :P

Comment: Too bad, in America there is a huge business of recovering homes from water damage and we have all sorts of kit for that, much of it rentable, including plastic-encased squirrel cage fans and dehumidifiers.  Carpets need favorable conditions to dry out, British damp does not qualify.

Comment: @isherwood I didn't realise there was a distinction. So do Mericans rent stuff, but hire people?

Comment: Yes. I'm only teasing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to do is extract the water, then dry with fans. Rather than renting a cleaner again, borrow or rent a large wet/dry vacuum. Use the [floor attachment](https://mobileimages.lowes.com/product/converted/026282/026282906779.jpg) and move slowly across the carpet in overlapping rows, giving the vacuum time to draw the water out of the pad and carpet.

Once you've removed as much liquid water as you reasonably can, get fans going. The more the better. Then, exhaust the damp air from the building using bath fans, window fans, and the HVAC system. Run the heat a bit higher than normal to assist drying and move air.

Finally, apply a carpet freshener according to the instructions on the package to remove and cover odor.

Time is of the essence at this point as mold and mildew are well established. Good luck.

Comment: Annoyingly I am not going to be able to get the chance to 'hire' a vacuum in time (kids/work etc..), but might be able to get to the shops tomorrow evening to get hold some kind of heated fan. Am currently making the best use of hair dryer... better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: With respect, you're wasting your time. You need to move air throughout the room and out of the building. Even a small household fan across the floor is far better than the dryer.

Comment: Fair enough. My tears are probably soaking the carpet more than the dryer is drying! I'll see if I can get a fan tomorrow. Luckily it is quite a windy night so I am getting a fair draft coming in through the open windows..

Comment: Thanks. So a day later, it seem just keeping the windows open to keep the air flow going has sorted things out. The following morning the smell had gone. I have spent this evening moving a fan heater over the carpet and it now feels pretty dry. I will apply some carpet freshener tomorrow to add the final touch.